# Alamofire download in MacOS. Looks fine, progresses is working, but no file?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have Alamofire added through cocoapods and I have a method going to download a zip file (approx 50Mb).

While downloading everything looks perfect.  I can see in Activity Monitor that 50Mb is downloaded for my app, I can see the progressbar zinging across.  But I can never find the file.

Right now I have it set to use the current directory, but have tried others just in case.  I have even searched the entire drive by data modified and never find anything.

Here is my code.

```
    func downloadAndInstall(){
        log.info("Downloading and Installing.....")
        displayToUser(content: "Downloading and Installing.....")

        let urlString = updatePackageURL //(This is http://xxxx.com/xxxxpackage.zip)
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        currentDir = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
        let fileURL: URL = URL(string: currentDir + "/package.zip")!
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in (fileURL, []) }
        log.info("FILEURL: \(fileURL)")
        var progressValues: [Double] = []
        var response: DefaultDownloadResponse?

        Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination)
            .downloadProgress { progress in
                progressValues.append(progress.fractionCompleted)
                log.info("Latest Progress Value: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                self.progBar.doubleValue = progress.fractionCompleted
            }
            .response { resp in
                response = resp
                if progressValues.last != 1.0 {
                    //backout of the process, something went wrong
                    log.debug("Something went wrong downloading the file.  Close and try again.")
                    self.displayToUser(content: "Something went wrong downloading the file. Close and try again.")
                    self.exitpoorly()
                }
                else{
                    log.info("Download Finished")
                    self.displayToUser(content: "Download Finished")
                    self.extractpackage()
                }
        }

        var previousProgress: Double = progressValues.first ?? 0.0

        for progress in progressValues {
            previousProgress = progress
        }

        if let lastProgressValue = progressValues.last {
            log.info("Current Download Value: \(lastProgressValue, 1.0)")
        } else {
            //Fail
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest checking for any errors, e.g.:

```
Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination)
    .downloadProgress { progress in
        ...
    }
    .response { response in
        guard response.error == nil else {
            //backout of the process, something went wrong
            log.debug("Something went wrong downloading the file.  Close and try again.")
            log.debug(response.error!.localizedDescription)
            ...
            self.exitpoorly()
            return
        }

        log.info("Download Finished")
        ...
}
```

Maybe the app is sandboxed, or perhaps you don't have permissions for that folder. It's hard to say without seeing the error.

Comment: Turns out I have a problem with the file URL...   Told me exactly what I needed to see.  Thanks!